# React Native Testing Library: scroll FlatList to bottom

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library

I have a [`react-native FlatList`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) component with `onEndReached` event used to load more items.

I am testing the component with [`react-native-testing-library`](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/). The test is as follows:

- Component mounted.
- Requests 10 items to `mockedBackend`.
- Expect `FlatList` to render those 10 items.
- `fireEvent` `onEndReached` to ask for next page with some more items.
- Expect `FlatList` to render new items.

Test was failing because `FlatList` was not rendering new items even thought `FlatList's data` property was being updated (I used `act` and `waitFor` as needed).

I managed to make the test pass when I fired `onScroll` event to bottom after some tries with hardcoded values.

Is there a way to make a helper to scroll to bottom taking into account proper `FlatList` size?

Helper to improve:

```js
export const scrollListToBottom = (list: ReactTestInstance) => {
  // FIXME: improve to get real list size
  // After some tries these hardcoded values allowed to pass the test
  act(() => {
    fireEvent.scroll(list, {
      nativeEvent: {
        contentSize: {height: 500, width: 100},
        contentOffset: {y: 400, x: 0},
        layoutMeasurement: {height: 100, width: 100},
      }
    })
  })

  // FIXME: if onScroll works perfectly is this even needed?
  act(() => {
    fireEvent(list, 'onEndReached')
  })
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import { act, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';

export const scrollListToBottom = async (list) => {
  // Find the scrollable view within the FlatList
  const scrollableView = list.findByProps({ testID: 'flatlist-scrollable' });

  // Get the height of the content within the FlatList
  const contentHeight = scrollableView.props.contentSize.height;

  // Calculate the scroll position to reach the bottom
  const scrollPosition = {
    x: 0, // Horizontal scroll position
    y: contentHeight, // Scroll to the calculated content height
  };

  // Scroll to the calculated position
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.scroll(scrollableView, { contentOffset: scrollPosition });
  });

  // Trigger the onEndReached event
  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent(list, 'onEndReached');
  });
};
```